# RPM and YUM not working on Centos7

Tags: centos7, yum, rpm

When I try to use `yum update` or install package by rpm the below error happened:
`rpm: /lib64/libnssutil3.so: version 'NSSUTIL_3.59' not found (required by /lib64/libnss3.so)`
How can I Fix this issue?

OS: `Centos7`

Comment: Tell us more about this system. Is it a vanilla CentOS 7 system? Did you install it yourself or was it provided to you by someone else (such as a hosting provider)? Have added any non-official yum repositories? It looks something may have been installed from a newer distribution and cannot run with the shared libraries available on CentOS 7.

Comment: @larsks Hi there, It is installed by hosting provider with Cpanel and WHM installed. And now there are a lot of website on it so I can't reinstall the OS. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: I think it's going to be a bit of a tricky fix, since the `rpm` command itself is broken. You might be able to copy both `/lib64/libnss3.so` and `/lib64/libnssutil3.so` from another CentOS 7 system (good sources are a centos docker image or one of their cloud disk images) and see if that resolves your problem.

Comment: 7-Zip is also capable of reading RHEL 8- archives and `rpm2cpio` might still work to try and extract a working libnss. In any case, you'd better make sure you have good backups at this stage.